# Is it possible to track a user's navigation through a website using php? If so, how?

Tags: php, web, navigation

On a website I'm making, I would like to know how a user landed on a particular page (say here.php). There could be two possible ways: by clicking the link on page1.php or the link on page2.php. How can I find out how the user reached, so that I can provide content according to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### HTTP_REFERER

[`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) should give you page the user has arrived from:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. **In short, it cannot really be trusted.**

### Using a session

If you want to track a users progress through your site then it would be easier/safer to set a session ([`session_start()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/session_start)) and use that to track them as they land on your pages.

Comment: ...but should *never* be relied on for anything that is actually important!! It is ridiculously easy for the user to manipulate. +1 though...

Comment: @DaveRandom agreed. I have updated the answer with the manual excerpt and emboldened its caveat! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could include a snipped of code in for example the footer of each page where you save the refferring page( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ), but also the current page. If you use the Session_id as a unique identifier for the visitor you are then able to see the history of each visitor.